Short story about the temptation of Jesus, with a twist
I'm looking for a short story I've read a couple years ago, but forgot where. It starts with the temptation of Jesus as described in the Bible, but then it has a plot twist: the devil shows the future of Christianity, that there will be billions of people who will believe in Jesus, but due to the law of large numbers there will be a few who are deluded that they are themselves Jesus. Then the devil asks Jesus how can He be sure to be the real Jesus, not just a mental patient imagining all this.
As I remember, the story is intentionally ambiguous, we don't get to know whether the main character was really Jesus with the story being set almost 2000 years ago, or just a mental patient in modern times.

It's not "The Last Temptation" by Neil Gaiman or "Divine Madness" by Roger Zelazny.
